# Streamline plot using tricontourf

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have four lists :
`x`, `y`, `u` and `v` where `u` is the x-component of velocity and `v` its y-component. You can find the dataset in the following
[link](https://file.io/JizATHK7yUNe).

I want to plot streamtraces using `ax.streamplot(x, y, u, v)` or something analogous.

The thing is, I don't use `meshgrid` here, as the mesh does not form a regular shape. Furthermore, `u` or `v` are not analytic, I just only have access to `u[i]` at `x[i]` and `y[i]`. How can I still plot streamlines ?

For the moment I was able to plot a 2D contour using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


path = "path/Example_stack_exchange.dat" 

#Open file
file = open(path)
lines = file.readlines()
lines.pop(0)


R = [] #Get each column into a data list
indexes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

for k in range (0, len(indexes)):
    R.append([])
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    for k in range(0, len(indexes)):
        R[k].append(float(line[indexes[k]]))

x    = R[0]
y    = R[1]
u    = R[2]
v    = R[3]
q    = R[4]

#Figure 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(bottom = True, left = True, right = True, top = True, labelsize = 'xx-large') 
CS = ax.tricontourf(x, y, q, cmap = 'jet', extend = 'both')
cbar = fig.colorbar(CS)
plt.show()
```

What I get is a 2D map of $\sqrt{u ^2 + v^2}$ on which I'd like to plot those streamlines:

[image]

I've tried `ax.streamplot(np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(u), np.array(v))`, but it doesn't work as my array is not equally spaced. Is there a way with such a configuration to plot streamlines (with matplotlib or not)?

---

Following is 400 rows of sample data. I'm not sure if this is sufficient to reproduce the desired result.

`'sqrt(u**2 + v**2)'` is calculate to conserve space, opposed to pasting the values.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'x': [1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.150666714, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332, 1.151333332], 'y': [-0.2133333385, -0.2120000124, -0.2106666565, -0.2093333304, -0.2079999894, -0.2066666633, -0.2053333372, -0.2039999962, -0.2026666701, -0.201333344, -0.1999999881, -0.198666662, -0.1973333359, -0.1960000098, -0.1946666688, -0.1933333278, -0.1920000017, -0.1906666607, -0.1893333346, -0.1880000085, -0.1866666675, -0.1853333265, -0.1840000004, -0.1826666594, -0.1813333333, -0.1800000072, -0.1786666662, -0.1773333251, -0.175999999, -0.1746666729, -0.1746666729, -0.173999995, -0.1733333319, -0.1726666689, -0.1720000058, -0.1713333279, -0.1706666648, -0.1700000018, -0.1693333387, -0.1686666608, -0.1679999977, -0.1673333347, -0.1666666716, -0.1660000086, -0.1653333306, -0.1646666676, -0.1639999896, -0.1633333266, -0.1626666635, -0.1620000005, -0.1613333374, -0.1606666744, -0.1599999964, -0.1593333334, -0.1586666703, -0.1580000073, -0.1573333442, -0.1566666663, -0.1559999883, -0.1553333253, -0.1546666622, -0.1539999992, -0.1533333361, -0.1526666731, -0.15200001, -0.1513333321, -0.150666669, -0.150000006, -0.149333328, -0.148666665, -0.1480000019, -0.147333324, -0.1466666609, -0.1459999979, -0.1453333348, -0.1446666718, -0.1440000087, -0.1433333457, -0.1426666677, -0.1419999897, -0.1413333267, -0.1406666636, -0.1400000006, -0.1393333375, -0.1386666596, -0.1379999965, -0.1373333335, -0.1366666704, -0.1360000074, -0.1353333443, -0.1346666664, -0.1340000033, -0.1333333254, -0.1326666623, -0.1319999993, -0.1313333362, -0.1306666732, -0.1299999952, -0.1293333322, -0.1286666691, -0.1280000061, -0.1273333281, -0.1266666651, -0.126000002, -0.125333339, -0.1246666685, -0.123999998, -0.1233333349, -0.1226666719, -0.1220000014, -0.1213333383, -0.1206666753, -0.1199999973, -0.1193333268, -0.1186666638, -0.1180000007, -0.1173333302, -0.1166666672, -0.1160000041, -0.1153333336, -0.1146666706, -0.1140000075, -0.113333337, -0.1126666591, -0.111999996, -0.111333333, -0.1106666625, -0.1099999994, -0.1093333364, -0.1086666659, -0.1080000028, -0.1073333398, -0.1066666692, -0.1060000062, -0.1053333282, -0.1046666652, -0.1039999947, -0.1033333316, -0.1026666686, -0.1019999981, -0.101333335, -0.100666672, -0.09999999404, -0.09933333099, -0.09866666794, -0.09800000489, -0.09733333439, -0.09666666389, -0.09600000083, -0.09533333033, -0.09466666728, -0.09400000423, -0.09333333373, -0.09266666323, -0.09200000018, -0.09133332968, -0.09066666663, -0.09000000358, -0.08933333308, -0.08866666257, -0.08799999952, -0.08733333647, -0.08666666597, -0.08600000292, -0.08533333242, -0.08466666937, -0.08399999887, -0.08333333582, -0.08266666532, -0.08199999481, -0.08133333176, -0.08066666871, -0.07999999821, -0.07933333516, -0.07866667211, -0.07799999416, -0.07733333111, -0.07666666806, -0.07600000501, -0.07533333451, -0.074666664, -0.07400000095, -0.07333333045, -0.0726666674, -0.07200000435, -0.07133333385, -0.07066666335, -0.0700000003, -0.0693333298, -0.06866666675, -0.0680000037, -0.06733333319, -0.06666666269, -0.06599999964, -0.06533333659, -0.06466666609, -0.06400000304, -0.06333333254, -0.06266666949, -0.06199999899, -0.06133333594, -0.06066666916, -0.05999999866, -0.05933333188, -0.05866666511, -0.05800000206, -0.05733333528, -0.0566666685, -0.055999998, -0.05533333123, -0.05466666818, -0.0540000014, -0.05333333462, -0.05266666412, -0.05199999735, -0.0513333343, -0.05066666752, -0.04999999702, -0.04933333397, -0.04866666719, -0.04800000042, -0.04733333364, -0.04666666687, -0.04600000009, -0.04533333331, -0.04466666654, -0.04399999976, -0.04333333299, -0.04266666621, -0.04199999943, -0.04133333266, -0.04066666588, -0.03999999911, -0.03933333606, -0.03866666555, -0.0380000025, -0.037333332, -0.03666666523, -0.03600000218, -0.03533333167, -0.0346666649, -0.03400000185, -0.03333333135, -0.0326666683, -0.03200000152, -0.03133333474, -0.03066666797, -0.02999999933, -0.02933333255, -0.02866666764, -0.027999999, -0.027999999, -0.02666666731, -0.02533333376, -0.02400000021, -0.02266666666, -0.0213333331, -0.01999999955, -0.018666666, -0.01733333245, -0.01600000076, -0.01466666628, -0.01333333366, -0.0120000001, -0.01066666655, -0.009333333001, -0.00800000038, -0.006666666828, -0.005333333276, -0.00400000019, -0.002666666638, -0.001333333319, -0.1746666729, -0.173999995, -0.1733333319, -0.1726666689, -0.1720000058, -0.1713333279, -0.1706666648, -0.1700000018, -0.1693333387, -0.1686666608, -0.1679999977, -0.1673333347, -0.1666666716, -0.1660000086, -0.1653333306, -0.1646666676, -0.1639999896, -0.1633333266, -0.1626666635, -0.1620000005, -0.1613333374, -0.1606666744, -0.1599999964, -0.1593333334, -0.1586666703, -0.1580000073, -0.1573333442, -0.1566666663, -0.1559999883, -0.1553333253, -0.1546666622, -0.1539999992, -0.1533333361, -0.1526666731, -0.15200001, -0.1513333321, -0.150666669, -0.150000006, -0.149333328, -0.148666665, -0.1480000019, -0.147333324, -0.1466666609, -0.1459999979, -0.1453333348, -0.1446666718, -0.1440000087, -0.1433333457, -0.1426666677, -0.1419999897, -0.1413333267, -0.1406666636, -0.1400000006, -0.1393333375, -0.1386666596, -0.1379999965, -0.1373333335, -0.1366666704, -0.1360000074, -0.1353333443, -0.1346666664, -0.1340000033, -0.1333333254, -0.1326666623, -0.1319999993, -0.1313333362, -0.1306666732, -0.1299999952, -0.1293333322, -0.1286666691, -0.1280000061, -0.1273333281, -0.1266666651, -0.126000002, -0.125333339, -0.1246666685, -0.123999998, -0.1233333349, -0.1226666719, -0.1220000014, -0.1213333383, -0.1206666753, -0.1199999973, -0.1193333268, -0.1186666638, -0.1180000007, -0.1173333302, -0.1166666672, -0.1160000041, -0.1153333336, -0.1146666706, -0.1140000075, -0.113333337, -0.1126666591, -0.111999996, -0.111333333, -0.1106666625, -0.1099999994, -0.1093333364, -0.1086666659, -0.1080000028, -0.1073333398, -0.1066666692, -0.1060000062, -0.1053333282, -0.1046666652, -0.1039999947, -0.1033333316, -0.1026666686, -0.1019999981, -0.101333335, -0.100666672, -0.09999999404, -0.09933333099, -0.09866666794, -0.09800000489, -0.09733333439, -0.09666666389, -0.09600000083, -0.09533333033, -0.09466666728, -0.09400000423, -0.09333333373, -0.09266666323, -0.09200000018, -0.09133332968, -0.09066666663, -0.09000000358], 'u': [0.8440005183, 0.8456072807, 0.847221911, 0.8489233255, 0.8506996036, 0.852542758, 0.8544641137, 0.8564633727, 0.8585450649, 0.8607202768, 0.862995863, 0.8653701544, 0.8678442836, 0.8704157472, 0.8730685711, 0.8758332133, 0.8787766099, 0.8818724155, 0.8850632906, 0.888455987, 0.8921025991, 0.8956739902, 0.8991770744, 0.9035494328, 0.90847826, 0.9117833376, 0.9147781134, 0.9223377109, 0.9310883284, 0.9304597974, 0.9304617047, 0.9280014634, 0.9255425334, 0.9281987548, 0.9387146235, 0.9552482963, 0.9685966372, 0.9646108747, 0.9343885779, 0.8692393899, 0.7692342401, 0.6411761642, 0.5001422763, 0.3614704013, 0.2372124046, 0.1353996843, 0.05628485233, -0.0008841814706, -0.04097124562, -0.06859730929, -0.08864098042, -0.1038448215, -0.115413636, -0.123858057, -0.1295538545, -0.1333255023, -0.1357364953, -0.136844039, -0.1366489083, -0.1352561563, -0.1329476684, -0.1299996674, -0.1264719963, -0.122305572, -0.1176328808, -0.1127020568, -0.1075685397, -0.1021128744, -0.09618278593, -0.08985507488, -0.08334593475, -0.07660610974, -0.06945114583, -0.06197281554, -0.05439769477, -0.04683668539, -0.03925932571, -0.03166099638, -0.02397876233, -0.01595827565, -0.007554290351, 0.0009576231241, 0.009389562532, 0.01786782034, 0.02658477984, 0.03548005968, 0.04454417527, 0.05390105769, 0.06338468939, 0.07272238284, 0.08220497519, 0.09237223864, 0.103002876, 0.1135903895, 0.1240175664, 0.1343846321, 0.144829616, 0.1554675996, 0.1665068865, 0.1780579239, 0.1898940653, 0.2015721649, 0.2130566537, 0.2246615291, 0.2364491373, 0.248342827, 0.260612756, 0.2734426558, 0.2865381241, 0.2997617424, 0.3133200109, 0.3272152543, 0.3413023055, 0.355482161, 0.3696518242, 0.3838107288, 0.3981080353, 0.4126470089, 0.4275863171, 0.4428671598, 0.4580691457, 0.4731273949, 0.4882441461, 0.5034220815, 0.518653214, 0.5339225531, 0.5490561128, 0.563980937, 0.5787212849, 0.5932276249, 0.6075471044, 0.6217148304, 0.6356002092, 0.6491828561, 0.6624788642, 0.6752497554, 0.6873281002, 0.6988062263, 0.7097887397, 0.7203564048, 0.7303744555, 0.7396486998, 0.748259604, 0.7562744021, 0.7636945844, 0.7706341147, 0.7770217657, 0.7826491594, 0.7874631882, 0.7916582227, 0.7953503728, 0.7985497713, 0.8012617826, 0.8034821749, 0.805193305, 0.8063738942, 0.8070875406, 0.8074029684, 0.8073691726, 0.8070088029, 0.8062945008, 0.8052771091, 0.8039849401, 0.802377522, 0.800429225, 0.7981642485, 0.7956289053, 0.7928802371, 0.7899430394, 0.7868754864, 0.7836967111, 0.7804057002, 0.7769716382, 0.7733314037, 0.7695144415, 0.7656156421, 0.7617049217, 0.7577517033, 0.7537409663, 0.7496634722, 0.7455491424, 0.7414103746, 0.7372864485, 0.7332382202, 0.7293328047, 0.7255778313, 0.7219690084, 0.7185050249, 0.7152072787, 0.712143302, 0.7093732953, 0.7069116235, 0.7047415972, 0.7028734684, 0.7013348341, 0.7001767159, 0.6994231939, 0.6990889907, 0.6991709471, 0.6996921897, 0.7006720901, 0.7021142244, 0.7039985061, 0.7062476277, 0.7088525891, 0.7118596435, 0.7152925134, 0.7191780806, 0.72346735, 0.7281149626, 0.7331019044, 0.7383624911, 0.7438424826, 0.7495248318, 0.7553986311, 0.7614982128, 0.7678320408, 0.7743608952, 0.7810297012, 0.7877651453, 0.7945196033, 0.8012912869, 0.8080794811, 0.8148549795, 0.8216207623, 0.8283429146, 0.8349916339, 0.8415215015, 0.8479167223, 0.8542021513, 0.8603924513, 0.8665047884, 0.8724956512, 0.87837255, 0.884129405, 0.8897840381, 0.895309031, 0.9006474018, 0.9058100581, 0.9107730389, 0.9155442715, 0.920112431, 0.9244583845, 0.9286152124, 0.9325935841, 0.9363866448, 0.9399418235, 0.943271935, 0.9465030432, 0.9497672319, 0.9530867338, 0.953085959, 0.959929049, 0.9669618011, 0.9739598632, 0.980710566, 0.9871976972, 0.9934850931, 0.9996219873, 1.00558722, 1.01131475, 1.016723871, 1.021752715, 1.026358485, 1.030512571, 1.03421855, 1.037523389, 1.040456057, 1.043049574, 1.045332193, 1.047341824, 1.049142957, 0.9299257398, 0.9276010394, 0.9269128442, 0.9323197603, 0.9452293515, 0.9611909986, 0.9688054919, 0.9550501704, 0.9123295546, 0.8339757919, 0.7236566544, 0.5910950899, 0.4518047273, 0.3197339773, 0.2045387179, 0.1118625253, 0.04054531828, -0.01108979341, -0.04761756957, -0.07325652242, -0.09221214801, -0.1067105681, -0.1177346483, -0.1257670224, -0.1311564893, -0.1346812099, -0.1368635893, -0.1377539188, -0.1373408139, -0.135708496, -0.1331026852, -0.1298718303, -0.1260759681, -0.121588856, -0.1166725382, -0.1116894782, -0.1065256745, -0.1008667946, -0.09462654591, -0.08806064725, -0.08139494807, -0.07450533658, -0.06722072512, -0.05963306502, -0.05193982646, -0.04430793971, -0.03667755798, -0.02896358259, -0.02110251971, -0.01288269181, -0.004282994661, 0.004444536753, 0.013100137, 0.02171367221, 0.03048199601, 0.03947336227, 0.04867462441, 0.05812922493, 0.06773404032, 0.07727491856, 0.08698306233, 0.0972674191, 0.1078677922, 0.1184684038, 0.1290479302, 0.1396042407, 0.1501751542, 0.1609106958, 0.1721087694, 0.1838621199, 0.1958778948, 0.2077542245, 0.2194837034, 0.2312891483, 0.2431509942, 0.2550637126, 0.2673272192, 0.2800964415, 0.2931647897, 0.3064967096, 0.3202050328, 0.3341825902, 0.3483100533, 0.3624828756, 0.376562953, 0.3906257749, 0.4048941433, 0.4194886982, 0.434548825, 0.4498303533, 0.4648924172, 0.4798415303, 0.4949399531, 0.5101038218, 0.5252494812, 0.5403815508, 0.5553086996, 0.5700208545, 0.5845834017, 0.5989308357, 0.6131032705, 0.6270708442, 0.6407140493, 0.6540432572, 0.6670078039, 0.6794090271, 0.6911838651, 0.7024542093, 0.7132611871, 0.7236118913, 0.733322084, 0.7422690392, 0.7505734563, 0.7582921982, 0.7654765844, 0.7721742988, 0.778257966, 0.7835524082, 0.7880979776, 0.7920847535, 0.7956009507, 0.7986111045, 0.8011199832, 0.8031573296, 0.8046887517, 0.8057078123, 0.8062602878, 0.8064354658], 'v': [-0.2477927059, -0.2498780787, -0.2519990504, -0.2541511655, -0.2563433647, -0.2585861683, -0.2608652413, -0.2631977499, -0.2655796409, -0.2680135071, -0.270498544, -0.2730379999, -0.2756352127, -0.2782843113, -0.2809817791, -0.2837443948, -0.2865916491, -0.2895077169, -0.2924604714, -0.2955133021, -0.2987075746, -0.3018555343, -0.3049555421, -0.3084657788, -0.3122426271, -0.3152010739, -0.3180212975, -0.3230286241, -0.3282620013, -0.3293458223, -0.3293454647, -0.3290726542, -0.3288023174, -0.3311268091, -0.3361614048, -0.3431329429, -0.3480832577, -0.3456796408, -0.3327547908, -0.3062673211, -0.2671049535, -0.2189214528, -0.16828309, -0.1208886728, -0.08143886179, -0.05145062134, -0.03047871962, -0.01633184403, -0.007004206069, -0.0008462457336, 0.003606073093, 0.007152454928, 0.01003937982, 0.01241111569, 0.01439689565, 0.01608007215, 0.01752955467, 0.01877118088, 0.01974574849, 0.02040994726, 0.02080722153, 0.02097551525, 0.02091824263, 0.0205445718, 0.01986579783, 0.01911742799, 0.01843352616, 0.01766236499, 0.01661412418, 0.01526697818, 0.0136982007, 0.01195670478, 0.01010321267, 0.008191295899, 0.006108303554, 0.003757941537, 0.001197007485, -0.001570671331, -0.004568939563, -0.007719800808, -0.01091886684, -0.01420862414, -0.01765407994, -0.02117036656, -0.02472528815, -0.02848524041, -0.0325130038, -0.0367227383, -0.04111114517, -0.04568238184, -0.05036186054, -0.05513927713, -0.05999642611, -0.06488838047, -0.0698536858, -0.07489383966, -0.08002155274, -0.08530690521, -0.09087952971, -0.09676983953, -0.1028654128, -0.109105885, -0.1155495644, -0.1222328916, -0.1290296614, -0.1357969344, -0.1425154954, -0.149187237, -0.155788675, -0.1623524576, -0.1690064967, -0.1758822948, -0.1829736531, -0.1901346594, -0.1972661763, -0.2043252736, -0.2112624794, -0.2180899531, -0.2250609398, -0.2323287278, -0.2396304756, -0.2467167526, -0.2536240518, -0.2604509592, -0.2671720982, -0.2737804651, -0.2802223265, -0.2864308655, -0.2924990058, -0.298460722, -0.3042773604, -0.3098621964, -0.315097779, -0.3200243413, -0.3246874213, -0.3290669024, -0.3331571221, -0.3370291889, -0.3407107592, -0.3441765308, -0.3473581374, -0.3501937985, -0.3527132571, -0.3549863994, -0.3570584953, -0.3589394689, -0.3605193198, -0.3617245555, -0.3626113236, -0.3632766604, -0.3637542129, -0.3640173078, -0.3640635312, -0.3639045954, -0.3635267317, -0.3629489541, -0.3621834219, -0.361271143, -0.3602762222, -0.3592311442, -0.3580901921, -0.3568128943, -0.3553927243, -0.3538479209, -0.3522129655, -0.3505038917, -0.3487330079, -0.3468992412, -0.3449902833, -0.3430505693, -0.3411104381, -0.3391451836, -0.3371034563, -0.3349503577, -0.3327209949, -0.330506295, -0.3283320665, -0.3261492848, -0.3239153326, -0.3216412365, -0.3193577826, -0.3170776069, -0.3148204982, -0.3126135468, -0.310465008, -0.3083615303, -0.3063145876, -0.3043662906, -0.3025376201, -0.3008216918, -0.2992015183, -0.2976738811, -0.2962274253, -0.2948657274, -0.2936398685, -0.2926014662, -0.2917888165, -0.2911778688, -0.2907269001, -0.290423274, -0.2902754545, -0.2903006375, -0.2905108631, -0.2909055352, -0.2914842069, -0.2922331691, -0.2931343913, -0.2941732705, -0.2953504324, -0.2966697216, -0.2981157303, -0.2996790707, -0.3013311327, -0.3030517101, -0.3048433661, -0.3067067266, -0.3086442947, -0.3106412888, -0.3126763105, -0.314720124, -0.316747278, -0.3187665939, -0.3207813799, -0.3228046298, -0.3248288631, -0.3268430233, -0.3288300931, -0.3307754993, -0.3326630294, -0.3345001638, -0.3362989128, -0.3380572796, -0.339769572, -0.3414264619, -0.3430300951, -0.3445824385, -0.3460771143, -0.3475059569, -0.3488759995, -0.3501825035, -0.351413846, -0.3525619507, -0.3536174893, -0.3545970619, -0.3555143774, -0.3563687801, -0.3571432531, -0.357834518, -0.3584959805, -0.3591738045, -0.3598538339, -0.3598553836, -0.3612807989, -0.3627663851, -0.3642188907, -0.3655812144, -0.3668420017, -0.3680243194, -0.3691387475, -0.370182097, -0.3711302876, -0.3719579875, -0.3726311624, -0.3731352985, -0.3734633327, -0.3736224174, -0.3736292422, -0.3734939098, -0.3732337058, -0.3728587925, -0.3723761737, -0.3718082905, -0.3255228698, -0.3249186575, -0.3257373869, -0.3288525045, -0.3345687389, -0.3407540321, -0.342887193, -0.336374402, -0.3184246123, -0.2874221206, -0.2455015779, -0.197180897, -0.1489206403, -0.1057520285, -0.07111667842, -0.04536184669, -0.02755865641, -0.01560493838, -0.007568962406, -0.001919063274, 0.002357345074, 0.00574830221, 0.008499148302, 0.01080454607, 0.01278856024, 0.01443342399, 0.01571656577, 0.01667575538, 0.01733626612, 0.01776203141, 0.0180420801, 0.01816432364, 0.01806302369, 0.01765298285, 0.01698774286, 0.01623518206, 0.01548761781, 0.0146475574, 0.01351844892, 0.01204803959, 0.01029318664, 0.008301493712, 0.006229255814, 0.004213418812, 0.002095227828, -0.0003055621637, -0.002949618734, -0.005804484244, -0.00885896571, -0.01203086786, -0.01525103953, -0.01856403798, -0.02202457376, -0.02559223399, -0.02923461981, -0.03306163475, -0.03715172783, -0.04143672809, -0.04585002363, -0.05042130128, -0.05517454445, -0.05999322236, -0.06470512599, -0.06934288144, -0.07413118333, -0.07918435335, -0.08442414552, -0.08979345858, -0.0953932479, -0.1012949944, -0.1073958576, -0.1136073619, -0.1200571433, -0.1268102527, -0.133623451, -0.1403385997, -0.1470201463, -0.1536509097, -0.1601727456, -0.1667299867, -0.1734807193, -0.1803877056, -0.1873870641, -0.1944466829, -0.2015054822, -0.2084666193, -0.2152918428, -0.2220517099, -0.2289911062, -0.2361806482, -0.24335666, -0.2503337264, -0.2571261823, -0.2637880743, -0.2703549266, -0.276863575, -0.283231765, -0.2893728018, -0.2953549325, -0.3011679053, -0.3068059981, -0.3122064471, -0.317276746, -0.3220879436, -0.3266612291, -0.3308876157, -0.3347753882, -0.3384556472, -0.3419784904, -0.345294714, -0.3482989669, -0.3509676754, -0.3533641398, -0.3555443883, -0.3575617373, -0.3593578935, -0.360783726, -0.3618172705, -0.3625804186, -0.3631655574, -0.3635709584, -0.3637557924, -0.363705337, -0.3634324074, -0.3629460335, -0.3622769117, -0.3614450395, -0.3604978025]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['sqrt(u**2 + v**2)'] = np.sqrt(df.u**2 + df.v**2)

x = df.x
y = df.y
u = df.u
v = df.v
q = df['sqrt(u**2 + v**2)']

#Figure 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(bottom = True, left = True, right = True, top = True, labelsize = 'xx-large') 
CS = ax.tricontourf(x, y, q, cmap = 'jet', extend = 'both')
cbar = fig.colorbar(CS)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is the data smooth that you can interpolate? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jared I've edited my answer to provide a reproductible example

Comment: I don't trust links to data files. Can you create an example that generates representative data?

Comment: I can generate random data but streamlines wont make sense and I can't check if it is consistent. The file I've uploaded is a .dat with numbers in column, how can I provide it "safely" ? There is like 50k rows

Comment: It's easier to read your data with `df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\\s+', skiprows=1, header=None)` and `df.columns = ['x', 'y', 'u', 'v', 'sqrt(u**2 + v**2)']`

Comment: If you're going to share a data file, which is not an accepted form of creating an [mre], then it should at least be on github, which is trusted. And no zipped files. SO questions are required to contain the data sample so the question can be reproduced by others in the future, otherwise the question become useless when the link to the file expires.